# Travel Nach set with Targum?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

I came upon a travel נ״ך set recently. It had some basic commentaries such as רש״י and מצודת דוד, however there was no Targum.

Are there any travel sets which have Targum as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff [like this](http://www.moshebooks.com/items/676885-%D7%A0-%D7%9A-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%93-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1-) are essentially pocket size prints of the full size. They have the same exact page layout as a full-size; including all the regular commentaries and Targum.